# How to migrate from request to axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, axios, cryptocurrency

I am using
[https://github.com/huobiapi/REST-Node.js-demo][1]
for my connection to huobi cryptocoin exchange but i am having some errors like :

```
 (node:29550) Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Undefined]
```

and

```
 GET /v1/account/accounts/15548622/balance
  { Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
 at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/ttr/node_modules/request/request.js:816:19)
 at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:285:13)
 at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:197:13)
 at TLSSocket.emitRequestTimeout (_http_client.js:668:40)
 at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:285:13)
 at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:197:13)
 at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:447:8)
 at listOnTimeout (timers.js:324:15)
 at processTimers (timers.js:268:5) code: 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT', connect: false }
```

I believe they are related to file:

```
  framework/httpClient.js
```

which has an outdated module
"request" can be changed to axios module so my errors may dissappear.

```
const http = require('http');
const request = require('request');
const moment = require('moment');
const logger = console;

var default_post_headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
}

var agentOptions = {
    keepAlive: true,
    maxSockets: 256,
}

exports.get = function(url, options) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        options = options || {};
        var httpOptions = {
            url: url,
            method: 'get',
            timeout: options.timeout || 3000,
            headers: options.headers || default_post_headers,
            proxy: options.proxy || '',
            agentOptions: agentOptions
        }
        request.get(httpOptions, function(err, res, body) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                if (res.statusCode == 200) {
                    resolve(body);
                } else {
                    reject(res.statusCode);
                }
            }
        }).on('error', logger.error);
    });
}

exports.post = function(url, postdata, options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        options = options || {};
        var httpOptions = {
            url: url,
            body: JSON.stringify(postdata),
            method: 'post',
            timeout: options.timeout || 3000,
            headers: options.headers || default_post_headers,
            proxy: options.proxy || '',
            agentOptions: agentOptions
        };
        request(httpOptions, function(err, res, body) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                if (res.statusCode == 200) {
                    resolve(body);
                } else {
                    reject(res.statusCode);
                }
            }
        }).on('error', logger.error);
    });
};

exports.form_post = function(url, postdata, options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        options = options || {};
        var httpOptions = {
            url: url,
            form: postdata,
            method: 'post',
            timeout: options.timeout || 3000,
            headers: options.headers || default_post_headers,
            proxy: options.proxy || '',
            agentOptions: agentOptions
        };
        request(httpOptions, function(err, res, body) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                if (res.statusCode == 200) {
                    resolve(body);
                } else {
                    reject(res.statusCode);
                }
            }
        }).on('error', logger.error);
    });
};
```

So far i tried :

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        options = options || {};
        var httpOptions = {
            url: url,
            method: 'get',
            timeout: options.timeout || 3000,
            headers: options.headers || default_post_headers,
            proxy: options.proxy || '',
            agentOptions: agentOptions
        }
        axios.get(httpOptions, function(err, res, body) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                if (res.statusCode == 200) {
                    resolve(body);
                } else {
                    reject(res.statusCode);
                }
            }
        }).on('error', logger.error);
    });
}
```

Solution like this but seems like they dont work exactly same so not worked.

```
 [1]: https://github.com/huobiapi/REST-Node.js-demo
```

Comment: Could you share the errors you have with adios? What's not working exactly.

Comment: errors listed above 2 different error first one comes always second comes sometime

Comment: Axios seems to target an internal path to your server is that expected? Or maybe doesn't it log the full url path?

Answer (score 1):

I just migrated from request to axios, and i recommand the following changes:

import qs package

```
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false / true,
    cert: <your cert>
    key: <your key> })



var httpOptions = {
    url: url
    data: qs.stringify(postdata)
    method: 'post',
    timeout: options.timeout || 3000,
    headers: options.headers || default_post_headers,
    proxy: options.proxy || '', (not sure about this)
    httpsAgent };
```

And this is the right way to send the request:

```
axios(httpOptions).then((resp)=>{
    // on success - for exmaple: console.log(response.status);
}).catch((err) => {
    //on failure - for example: return null;
});
```

your request on the one hand contains method:post and on the other hand you did axios.get
if your request payload contains method field, you can just run axios(options)

Answer (score 0):

i just removed bluebird from modules and errors gone.